# Error in index.js, where converApi.auth is not defined.?

Tags: convertapi

While running the below code

```
let convertApi = ConvertApi.auth({secret: '<YOUR_SECRET>'})
let elResult = document.getElementById('result')
let elResultLink = document.getElementById('resultLink')
elResult.style.display = 'none'
```

in index.js it is showing an error as ConvertApi.auth is not defined. How to resolve this?

The error code is:

```
let convertApi = ConvertApi.auth({secret: 'secret key'})
                 ^

ReferenceError: ConvertApi is not defined
```

Comment: Make sure that library is loaded prior usage.

Comment: @Jonas Yes i have added import ConvertApi from 'convertapi'. But it is showing import ConvertApi from 'convertapi';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module.      like this

Comment: Please add more information about how the library is included in your project.